# how to do ad-hoc searches on log data stored in HBase

Tags: search, hbase

I have log file data stored in HBase. What will be the fastest way to do quick searches on keywords in a log in HBase.
I read something about creating an inverted index, but I'm not clear how the index would look like or even how to create one?
I also looked at hbasene- https://github.com/akkumar/hbasene

Any pointers on how to go about the searching would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at solutions that integrate lucene (which is an inverted index + more interesting features like stemming etc.) with HBase. hbasene is one option but more complete solutions are [SolBase](https://github.com/Photobucket/Solbase) and [Lily](http://www.lilyproject.org/lily/index.html)

Comment: I have a separate application running that continuously stores data into HBase. So, can I just use Lily on top to do my searching? Or would I have to route my data through Lily?